# How to release new versions of an API?

Tags: php, android, mysql, amazon-web-services, slim

I've developed an app that consumes HTTP data. The API was made using Slim Framework and the database is MySQL using RDS from AWS.

It's working for now, no problem. But I need to release new versions, and that is the problem. I don't know what to do.

Considering that if I change something in the API/database, will affect anyone who has not updated the app yet.

How should I make it work? Forcing users to update the app?

I read about versioning API and migration methods using phinx, flyway, ... . But here, the problem is the database. I don't know how to do it automatically with the API and don't even know if it is the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new release of your application add User-Agent header to your requests.
This header will contain type of OS (Android/iOS) and version of your application (for example 2.0). On backend check this header and if app version is 2.0 and above use v2 version of database for request else 1.0 version.

Also I advice to add "You use out of date version of application. Please update" screen so you can force all users to update after some period of time.